# How can I initialize an array's argument to its default value?

Tags: php, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
function myfunc( $arg1, $arg2 = 'sth', $arg3 = 'sth else' ){
    // do stuff
}
```

Now I want to set a new value for `arg3` and keep the default defined value for `arg2`. How can I do that?

Something like this:

```
myfunc( true, <keep everything defined as default>, $arg3 = 'new value' );
```

The expected result is `sth` in [this fiddle](https://3v4l.org/dAEYp).

Comment: as per your `fiddle` you haven't defined `$arg2` before calling that function

Comment: your question is not clear please add some more explanation.

Comment: @YaseenAhmed I want to set a value for `arg3` without setting any value for `arg2`. As you see both `arg3` and `arg2` are optional. And I want to use the defined default value for `arg2`.

Comment: you can use array as argument and set the value inside function if not found.

Comment: @stack Do you want this ? https://3v4l.org/RntQ9

Comment: @SaadSuri nope .. As I said in the question, the expected result is `sth` in my fiddle. And in yours, the expected result is `array('sth','tth')`.

Comment: So you can make it array('sth'). unfortunately i can't eval this fiddle

Comment: I post the answer check it if you have any question let me know

Comment: @stack Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597114/php-default-function-parameter-values-how-to-pass-default-value-for-not-last

Answer (score 3):

A possible alternative would not have your function take 3 parameters, but only one, an array:

```
function my_function(array $value = array()) {
    // if set, use $value['key1']
    // if set, use $value['key2']
    // ...
}
```

And call that function like this:

```
my_function(array(
    'key1' => 'google',
    'key2' => 'yahoo'
));
```

This would allow you to:

1. accept any number of parameters
2. all of which could be optional

Hope it will helpful.